# OpenCV with QT on Maemo 5 (N900)

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, maemo, n900

Since the presentation by Eero Bragge at the[Amterdam devdays](http://stackoverflow.carsonified.com/events/amsterdam/) about QT / QT-Creator I've been looking for an excuse to try my hands at mobile development. Now this excuse has arrived in the form of the Nokia N900, my new phone!

My other hobby is computer vision, so my first Idea's for applications to try and build lie in that direction. My questions now are:

- Has anyone tried QT Creator + OpenCV + Maemo 5? I see there is a [year old port of opencv for Meamo Diablo (4.1)](https://garage.maemo.org/projects/opencv/) has anyone tried that one on Maemo 5?
- I see that improvements to the OpenCV
  port are were among the [Meamo google
  summer of code 2009 ideas](http://wiki.maemo.org/GSoC_2009/Project_ideas) that
  didn't make the cut. Is there work
  being done there?
- How easy is it to acquire images from
  the phone's camera and convert them
  to something opencv understands?
- Does anyone have any useful links to
  share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I see that improvements to the OpenCV port are were among the Meamo google summer of code 2009 ideas that didn't make the cut. Is there work being done there?"

The project was not select, and AFAIK the people involved didn't carry the project.

OpenCV seems to work under Maemo5 according to the discussion here: http://n2.nabble.com/OpenCV-for-Maemo5-td4172275.html#a4172275

Answer (score 2):

you can use gstreamer framework to acquire image from both cameras. `gst-camerabin` should work.

see: http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/wiki/CameraBin

Comment: Interesting. Have you used this at all? Are you aware of samples?

Comment: http://wiki.maemo.org/Documentation/Maemo_5_Developer_Guide/Using_Multimedia_Components/Camera_API_Usage
this one looks good.